# send php mail to mail addresses in a csv

Tags: php, email

I have about 50 000 application names and e mail addresses stored in a CSV. I want to send mails to all 50 000 e mail addresses and the name of the application will also be included in the mail. This requires the CSV to be uploaded first. I searched for a similar kind of a scenario but was unable to find an answer.

Comment: Really? You found no posts about file uploads, no posts about reading from a CSV file, and no posts about sending mails with PHP?

Comment: You should consider using some kind of mass emailing software.

Answer (score 2):

SLOW DOWN!

50,000 is a large distribution list. While you can do this yourself i would strongly suggest using some existing sofware to do it yourself, better still, a hosted solution.

If you do do this yourself, you MUST throttle the sending rate. Flat out, you'll send about 11,000-20,000 in an hour (estimate) but your target should be 2,000 per hour max. Otherwise you'll overload the mail queue, not be able to handle the bounces and quickly get yourself on a blacklist that takes you days to get off it. If you're on a shared hosting account - throttle back to 1,000 per hour (or clear it with your hosts first).

A common "free" solution is http://www.phplist.com (and they even offer a hosted version if this is a one-off). Hosted versions also offer more surely that the mail server won't get blocked by spam - there are several around, just google and check on prices.

If you are rolling your own, to enable throttling, upload to DB (see other answers) and also add a "sent" column, every minutee grab 10/20 that have not been sent, mark as sent and send them. Then wait another minute and repeat. You can do this via a cron or via a page refresh. (PHP List will handle this for you!)

But I'd strongly suggest a hosted solution or strucutred software than rolling your own for something this large.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php). After you figured out how to read the data, you'll have to send it. I'd not recommend using PHPs send function. Instead use a mail library.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions available to parse the CSV file in PHP and after parsing you will get the data in an array of PHP variable. Take the array index in a loop and initiate the mail function with the data.